# Цикличный буфер в фоновом потоке

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

Имеется цикличный буфер, который непрерывно заполняется в фоновом потоке. Мне необходимо раз в секунду считывать его и обновлять UI интерфейс. Вопросы связанные с этим.

1. Использование async/await для заполнения буфера, правильно ли это?

   ```
   public async Task ReceiveAsync(CancellationToken ct)
   {
       await Task.Run(() => Receive(progressData));
       //в Receive() происходит получение пакетов/разбор из сети и запись в цикличный буфер. 
   }
   ```
2. Обновление UI раз в секунду я представляю себе так: передаю данные посредством `IProgress`:

   ```
   IProgress<DTO> progressData = new Progress<DTO>(progressHandler);
   ```

   Мне кажется этот способ не совсем верным, может можно читать напрямую из UI потока этот буфер который заполняется в другом потоке. Но тогда другой вопрос, чтение и запись одновременно? не возникнут ли проблемы при этом.

Comment: Покажите, что у вас внутри `Receive()`.

Comment: Получение пакетов/разбор из сети -- это полностью синхронный код?

Comment: @andreycha, да, поэтому я его запускаю в отдельном потоке.

Answer (score 2):

По первому пункту есть несколько замечаний:

1. Внутри `Receive()` у вас цикл. Как вы его будете прерывать? Не забывайте передавать `CancellationToken` внутрь, а также на запуск самого таска:

   ```
   public async Task ReceiveAsync(CancellationToken ct)
   {
       await Task.Run(() => Receive(progressData, ct), ct);
   }
   ```
2. Вы ожидаете где-то наверху таск, который возвращает `ReceiveAsync()`? Если нет, то могут возникнуть проблемы с исключениями. Либо обрабатывайте исключения внутри `Receive()`.
3. Ключевые слова async/await в данном случае избыточны, их можно опустить и просто возвращать таск:

   ```
   public Task ReceiveAsync(CancellationToken ct)
   {
       return Task.Run(() => Receive(progressData, ct), ct);
   }
   ```

---

По второму пункту: `IProgress<T>` и есть самый правильный способ уведомлять UI об изменениях. К тому же это потокобезопасный способ. Если вы можете красиво вложить в него информацию о том, что изменилось, то используйте его.

Если же каждый раз вы будете просто передавать в UI новый кусок вашего буфера, то возможно стоит подумать о том, чтобы UI самостоятельно читал обновления. Плюс вы упомянули, что обновление должно происходить раз в секунду, а это уже может быть невозможно для логики `Receive()`. Да и ни к чему может быть загрязнять логику чтения из сети логикой таймера.

Если будете обращаться к буферу напрямую из UI (или любого другого потока), то нужно будет синхронизировать доступ к нему: при помощи `lock` или `ReadWriteLockSlim`, если у вас может быть несколько читателей.

Comment: Спасибо за советы по первому пункту. При чтении из UI обязательно синхронизировать потоки? На данный момент я сделал без синхронизации. Как у меня устроено: класс буфера обернут другим классом  T, дальше List<T> привязан к UI. т.е. я добавляю новый объект T через Dispather Invoke. И уже при чтении буфера из UI потока никаких манипуляций c диспатчером и т.п. не делаю, это правильный подход? P.S. у меня один читатель.

Comment: @Gardes если тип `T` у вас неизменяемый, то проблем не будет.